# Unable to open x window from terminal for new users only

Tags: command-line, xorg, gui

I can open x window from terminal when I am logged in from my original account

However if I create a new account and switch into it using `su account-name` I am unable to open x window from terminal.

I get the following error:

```
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket:    Permission denied
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:26100): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution seems to be to login as original user and do:

```
xhost +[yourhostname]
```